# Uniqueness of equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

I have a model with two endogenous variables X and Y, and a set of parameters that I denote by $\omega$. Equilibrium $X^{*}(\omega)$ and $Y^{*}(\omega)$ in this model is the solution to:

\begin{align*}
F(X,Y;\omega)=0 \\
H(X,Y;\omega)=0
\end{align*}

I would like to know whether this equilibrium is unique (given parameters). I can prove that, if X is exogenously given, $Y^{*}(\omega, X)$ is uniquely determined. Similarly, I can prove that, if Y is exogenously given, $X^{*}(\omega, Y)$ is uniquely determined. Can I leverage these two results to show that the equilibrium with two endogenous variables is unique? I was thinking about proving it by contradiction, but not sure if it makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not without further assumptions. Let $F(X,Y)=H(X,Y)=|X-Y|$. This satisfies your assumptions, but every pair with $X=Y$ is an equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks! But can I leverage the uniqueness when only one variable is endogenous? I guess it is not enough, but maybe with some other element I can do it. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, in that case you have at most one equilibrium.

Comment: So just to clarify. If I can show that $X^{*}(Y,\omega)$ is unique and that $Y^{*}(X,\omega)$ is also unique. How can I then argue/prove that $(X(\omega),Y(\omega))$ is unique?

Comment: In that case, you have two endogenous variables, exactly as in the example. That is not enough for uniqueness.

Comment: OK thanks. So what else would I need?

Comment: What kind of assumptions make sense for your model and guarantee uniqueness is hard to say without knowing the model.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing ensures that will be a unique solution.

Indeed, on the contrary, saying

> I can prove that, if X is exogenously given, $Y^{*}(\omega, X)$ is
> uniquely determined. Similarly, I can prove that, if Y is exogenously
> given, $X^{*}(\omega, Y)$ is uniquely determined

you are stating that the system has  **infinite solutions.**$^1$

Consider your system, assuming a given value of $X$, say $X_1$.

\begin{align*}
F(X_1,Y;\omega)=0 \\
H(X_1,Y;\omega)=0
\end{align*}

According to your statement above, there is a unique $Y_1$ such that $(X_1,Y_1)$ is a solution.

That is, the pair $(X_1,Y_1)$ is a solution.

Now, re-consider the system with a different, given value of $X$, say $X_2$.

\begin{align*}
F(X_2,Y;\omega)=0 \\
H(X_2,Y;\omega)=0
\end{align*}

There will be a $Y_2$ such that $(X_2,Y_2)$ is a solution.

That is, the pair $(X_2,Y_2)$ is also a solution.

And so on.

**Assuming infinite given value of $X$, $X_i$, $i=1,2,...$ you have infinite solutions.**$^2$

$\;$

The second part of your statement

> Similarly, I can prove that, if Y is exogenously given, $X^{*}(\omega,
> > Y)$ is uniquely determined

just says that, for each given $Y_i$, there is a unique $X_i$, that is that the **$Y_i$ will be different from each other: $Y_i\neq Y_j$ for $i\neq j$** (actually, you are just stating that there is a bijection between the $X_i$ and the $Y_i$).

$\;$

For an example, if the two equations where linear, they would be linearly dependent, that is, they will  be two coincident lines.

$$***$$

Outside linear equations systems, **there isn't a general method** to state existence and unicity of the solutions of a system of equations.

A possible example where  the existence and unicity of the solution can be stated, for one single equation,  is the case of a **continuous strictly increasing function $f(x)$** on an interval $(a,b)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (it is a consequence of the Intermediate Value Theorem): the equation $f(x)=C$, $C\in\mathbb{R}$, has a unique solution in $(a,b)$.

An important theorem of mathematical analysis can be used, the [**Contraction mapping theorem or Banach-Caccioppoli fixed point theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), because many problems of finding the solutions of a system of equations can be viewed as a fixed-point  problem of a contraction mapping.

This theorem is used in numerical analysis to find solutions of equations,  but its  use in applications requires  sufficient information about the functions.

---

$^1$  <sup>Obviously, I understand that you mean that a solution exists, for any exogenously given $X$ or $Y$.</sup>

$^2$  <sup>Actually, there will be  a continuum of solutions, as $X$ varies in $\mathbb{R}$.</sup>